# Poweshell Set-ADUser ro populate Direct Reports

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, get-aduser

Hey I have been given a CVS file with the data that I must use to populate some already existing empty users. So far I have been able to populate all the data fields I need such as givenName, description, postalCode etc. However I have been unable to populate the user direct reports field. I am new to PowerShell, please see the code below for any errors.

```
Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path C:\script\PerthUsersa.csv | Foreach { 
     $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userPrincipalName)'"
    
    $DirectReport = Get-ADUser 

    if($ADUser) {
        Set-ADUser -Identity $ADUser -givenName $_.givenName -Surname $_.sn -DisplayName $_.displayName  -Description $_.description -Office $_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName -EmailAddress $_.mail -StreetAddress $_.streetAddress -City $_.l -State $_.st -PostalCode $_.postalCode -Title $_.title -Department $_.description  -MobilePhone $_.mobile -DirectReport $_.directReport
              
       } else {
         Write-Warning ("didnt get in " + $($_.userPrincipalName))
    }    
}
```

I expected this to also populate the direct report however I have been getting the following error instead:

```
Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DirectReports'.
At C:\script\perthUsers.ps1:5 char:343
+ ... hone $_.mobile -DirectReports $_.directReports
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your CSV, the `DirectReport` column what Values do you have? are them SamAccountNames, DistinguishedNames ? Do you have more than 1 value in each row ?

Answer (score 0):

The [`Reports` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-directreports) is not an attribute you can set manually, its managed by the system. What you can do instead is set the [`Manager` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-manager) of the users in the `DirectReport` column of your CSV.

The `-Manager` attribute from `Set-ADUser` allows the following values:

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A security identifier (objectSid)
- A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

If your column does not have one of these values then you will need to query Active Directory.

```bash
Import-Csv -Delimiter "," -Path C:\script\PerthUsersa.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userPrincipalName)'"

    if($ADUser) {
        $aduserSplat = @{
            givenName     = $_.givenName
            Surname       = $_.sn
            DisplayName   = $_.displayName
            Description   = $_.description
            Office        = $_.physicalDeliveryOfficeName
            EmailAddress  = $_.mail
            StreetAddress = $_.streetAddress
            City          = $_.l
            State         = $_.st
            PostalCode    = $_.postalCode
            Title         = $_.title
            Department    = $_.description
            MobilePhone   = $_.mobile
        }
        $ADUser | Set-ADUser @aduserSplat
        # here, if `$_.DirectReport` is not one of the mentioned values
        # you must query AD before
        $_.DirectReport | Set-ADUser -Manager $ADUser
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning ("Didnt get in " + $($_.userPrincipalName))
    }
}
```